# Combinations with limited overlap

Tags: combinatorics

How can we choose k-element combinations from an n-element set that have at least l elements different from other chosen combinations. Will the solution be unique?
The original set does not have duplicate elements and repetitions are not allowed while choosing k-element sets.
e.g. specific example  - From a set of 100 numbers, {1,2,3, ... 100}, how can we choose sets of 5 elements so that no two sets have more than 2 elements in common?

(Some context: Because of resource constraints, I cannot process all k-element combinations. I've to choose smaller set of combinations. I want to make sure they are diverse so I want to impose a constraint that no two chosen combinations should have more than l elements in common.
)

Here is what I tried in python using empirical approach but it's too slow when tried with (n=100, k=5, max_overlap=2)

`def get_combinations_indices( input_size, chosen_set_size , max_overlap=2):
    selected_combinations=list()
    for c in combinations(range(input_size), chosen_set_size):
        overlap_found=False
        if len(selected_combinations):
            for s in selected_combinations:
                if sum([ x in list(c) for x in s]) > max_overlap:
                    overlap_found=True
                    break
        if not overlap_found:
            selected_combinations.append(list(c))
    return selected_combinations`

Comment: What has been tried ? are you allowing repititions,  replacement, duplicates in the n element set ( making it technically a multiset)  ?

Comment: This affects the answer, that's why we ask. That and to know where you are struggling, and that at least we didn't give the full answer away to a student looking to pass a test, and not knowing the material.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the set of non-unique integer numbers
{ 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,7,8,9 }

If you are saying 1 chosen set has to have a unique number such as
10 then the set { 4,5,10 } is unique
then yes that particular set is unique and you have therefore
found your answer in that you can have a unique set and other
unique sets such as { 5,6,10 }

Your question however isn't very clear however.
It will depend also on what the intial n-element set contains.

Regards,

John O.

Comment: going through possible scenarios, is one reason I haven't answered.

Comment: Roddy and John, I edited the question to address your comments. Hope new description makes more sense.